# Window 10 connecting Monitors Touch and flatscreen

Tags: multiple-monitors

I installed windows 10 newest version all updates.
I connected a LCD-Touchscreen to my DVI-Port and a flatscreen TV to a Nvidia Geforce Grafics-card via HDMI- Port.
Both monitors work good and the screen settings are set to extended. The touchscreen works but the Windows Tabletmode is deactivatet. I cannot activate it unless I switch to a different screen setting. (Windowskey+P)
I even checked the Device manager and chnaged the Human interface devices. All had no effect on the  Tabletmode.
I cannot activate the tabletmode when the screen setting is set to extended. However I need this setup because I have a tool for touch and in the sametime a Video is running on the flatscreen.

I have tried the way to tell windows which one is the touchscreen. This also did not bring a solution.

Maybe somebody had a similar problem and got it solved. I would appreciate some help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot enable tablet mode while a second, non touch screen is connected.